# What does "teleport anywhere in the world" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition

The definition says:

> To transport by teleportation.

But what's not clear is if "teleport anywhere in the world" means "teleport from anywhere" or "teleport to anywhere" or "teleport to anywhere from anywhere".

Comment: to travel anywhere in the world, to drive anywhere in the country

Comment: Can you tell us the source of your defintion?

Comment: @blackbird, it is ***exactly the same as the word, say, "jump"***.  If I say "you can jump anywhere" it is ambiguous. (You can jump 'to' anywhere from where our discussion is taking place, or you can "do a jump" at any point.  It's absolutely the norm in English that sentences are ambiguous.  Something like 90% of sentences in English are ambiguous, it's the normal situation.

Comment: The meaning in context would depend on the context. If you have come across this somewhere, you could show the passage this is quoted from. Most likely it means "to anywhere," but the context might make us more certain of that or tell us it means something else.

Comment: teleport to anywhere.

Comment: No matter the whereto's - it does mean violating relativity.

Comment: Can you give some context? Lots of phrases are ambiguous on their own, but the meaning is clear from the context they appear in.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would understand it as *teleport **to** anywhere in the world*.

In context, it might also imply ***from** anywhere*, but that's a pragmatic conclusion, not part of the meaning.

Compare the verb *ship*:  "We ship anywhere" means "to any destination".

This is an interesting question, because *teleport* is a fairly recent word coined to refer to an imaginary phenonmenon, but English speakers unhesitatingly treat it like existing words such as *send* and *ship*.

Comment: Colin, actually the sentence "We ship anywhere" when used by say UPS in the US, specifically means the other sense.  ("You can do the act of shipping with us, pretty much anywhere - because we have so many offices in every city and town...")  Any word whatsoever in English that has a "doing location" and an "ancillary location" (such as "destination") has this ambiguity.  (Sure, one or the other may be more common in a given situation, but, so what, ambiguity is ambiguity.)

Comment: Just FWIW as a sci-fi reader!  I would probably disagree with your first sentence.  "You can teleport anywhere these days!" would likely mean "these days, there are teleport stations on every street corner and in every home, they're everywhere!" "teleport to..." is a more comfortable way of implying you mean the other sense.  (I'd say.)

Comment: furthermore "anywhere" would be an awkward way of saying "from this station, you can teleport to anywhere in the world".  You'd probably say, in that case, "from this station, you can teleport to any point on the Earth".  "anywhere" more goes with sense A. "These days, if you have the credits, you can teleport anywhere.", ie there are teleport devices commonly available everywhere.

Comment: It's not because of the word 'teleport' being new, it's just ambiguous (but understood by default to mean "teleport *to*).   Compare to "I can run anywhere in Texas": it could either mean "anywhere I go in Texas, I can run there" -or- "I can run to any place in Texas".

Comment: I don't agree with any of these comments, except Fattie's one about teleport stations. Maybe UPS meant "you can ship from anywhere", but it had never occurred to me that it even might mean that. I agree that, in a world in which teleport stations are a known thing, it could have that meaning. As for BadZen's analogy with "run", I don't accept it, because running doesn't have to be something doesn't have to be something you do from A to B: you can run _at_ a place. You can't ship or teleport _at_ a place, only _from_ or _to_.

Comment: Actually, in @Fattie's hypothetical world, you might teleport _at_ a place, but only if _teleport_ has come to behave like _post/mail_, rather than like _send_. It could do; but I don't believe it has in our world.

Comment: @BadZen *"but understood by default to mean "teleport to""* ...Hmm, I don't agree with that. Imagine we have teleporting, and retail companies like WalMart, UPS, Dunkin' Donuts offer the machine at their locations.  There would be a big sign out the front: **"Teleport here."** The word "teleport" is, simply, totally ambiguous:  ***like almost all words in English***.  Note that simply "jump" or "step" is utterly identically ambiguous to the word in question.  Note indeed that a native English speaker would *not even ask* "is X ambiguous"; you may as well ask "do politicans lie!" :)

Comment: You set up a specific context for your example; that's no longer a default!   Indeed though, in that context the meaning would be clear and you would be "teleporting (from) here", because you understand they were providing a terminus service.  

If on the other hand there was minimal or no context, say I called you on the phone and immediately said "run here"... do I mean "come here and run" or "run to where I am"?  Even that's a little contextual though, since in your example you're "already there" and in mine your are not.

Comment: So of course it is ambiguous, but there are defaults in ambiguity in language.   I strongly suspect without any context most people would say those words 'usually' meant "teleport (to) anywhere", however, because that's how the word is colored psychologically.  "Travel anywhere" is a more extremely (but still technically ambiguous) example. "Drive anywhere" is a less colored example, etc, etc

Answer (score 6):

It's "to anywhere" that's implied, in my opinion. (though, that'd also imply from anywhere, since you couldn't teleport *anywhere* if you couldn't teleport from where you were)

English can be vague.
Without clarification, a common sentence could mean a lot of things.

Comment: "English can be vague"  Indeed.  "can" in the sense that, say, "hookers can sometimes charge money"  :O

Comment: Re: "though, that'd also imply from anywhere": I don't understand why you say that. I see no problem with "This is an outbound teleportation hub; you can teleport anywhere from here."

Comment: @ruakh That's what I inferred from that sentence used in isolation. (e.g. add on a "to here" to the end) Heck, teleport could even be a noun (like airport), if you cared enough.